# Adding items into multiple arrrays in the same loop

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

In assignment, we have a class called `Product` and we need to need to create a an array for `Product` objects, and implement this array's methods (`delete`, `search`, `insert`) in a class called `ProductArray`. I wrote array operations successfully. However, I have a problem about adding `Product` objects into 2 different arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    ProductArray array1 = new ProductArray(50);
    ProductArray array2 = new ProductArray(50);
    File file = new File("/Users/S.nur/Downloads/Products.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
                  
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String whl = String.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        String[] split = whl.split(",");
        Product p = new Product(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
               
        array1.insert(p);
        array2.insert(p);   
    }
    array1.display();
    array2.display();
}
    
public class ProductArray {
    private int size;
    private static int count = 0;
    private Product []array;
    private int sortCost=0;
        
    ProductArray(int size){ 
        if (size < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be less than 0.");
        }
        this.size = size;
        array = new Product[size]; 
    }
            
    public void insert(Product p){
        if (count >= size) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Capacity is full.");
        } else {
            array[count++] = p; 
        }
    }
public void display (){
        for (int i= 0; i< count; i++){
            array[i].displayProduct();   
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got this exception in the console and I did not understand it. How can I fix it?

```
Product name: HUAWEI MATEBOOK D15, Description: AMD RYZEN 7 3700,
Price: 6799 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:
Cannot invoke "ceng202_lab1.Product.displayProduct()" because
"this.array[i]" is null     at
ceng202_lab1.ProductArray.display(ProductArray.java:141)    at
ceng202_lab1.TestProductArray.main(TestProductArray.java:36)
```

Comment: Please show us your implementation of the `display()` method in `ProductArray`

Comment: Format the exception as code. What was the purpose of the first paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "ceng202_lab1.Product.displayProduct()" 
because "this.array[i]" is null at
ceng202_lab1.ProductArray.display(ProductArray.java:141) at 
ceng202_lab1.TestProductArray.main(TestProductArray.java:36)
```

The error tells us that `this.array[i]` is null in the method `display()` of the class `ProductArray`.

In your code, the `count` property of `ProductArray` is static, meaning that it is shared by all instances, instead of being a different value for every instance of `ProductArray`.

This means, that if you insert a value into one instance of `ProductArray`, the `count`, that all instances share, is incremented.

If you then iterate over all products stored in one instance of `ProductArray` in your `display()` method, there will be some null values in your array:

```java
ProductArray array1 = new ProductArray(50);
ProductArray array2 = new ProductArray(50);

// ProductArray.count is 0
// Both instances of ProductArray have a separate array with 50 values, which are all null

Product p = new Product(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
               
array1.insert(p);
// This inserts a value into array1.array at position 0
// ProductArray.count is incremented to 1


array2.insert(p);   
// This inserts a value into array2.array at position 1
// ProductArray.count is incremented to 2
// array2.array[0] is left empty

for (int i = 0; i < ProductArray.count; i++) {
    array1.array[i].display()
    // will work with i = 0, this is the description that you can see printed in the console.
    // will crash with i = 1, because array1.array[1] is null
}

for (int i = 0; i < ProductArray.count; i++) {
    array2.array[i].display()
    // will crash with i = 0, because array2.array[0] is null
}
```

To fix this issue, you have to declare `count` **without** the `static` keyword, so that each instance has its own count.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Now, I understand the problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ceng202_lab1.Product.displayProduct()" because "this.array[i]" is null at

above error is coming because the newly created product is not inserted properly in the array1. Please check the insert method of ProductArray class and also if are you inserting a new product at the correct index in the array.

Below is one possible implementation of ProductArray Class with insert method :

```
public class ProductArray {
    Product[] productArray;

    public ProductArray(int size) {
        this.productArray = new Product[size];
    }
    
    /* index variable to insert product at next index, also since you want insert product in 2 different arrays of the ProductArray object,static variable will not be useful */
    public void insert(Product p, int index){
        productArray[index] = p;
    }
}
```

Changes in the driver Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{ 
            ProductArray array1 = new ProductArray(50);
            ProductArray array2 = new ProductArray(50);
            File file = new File("/Users/S.nur/Downloads/Products.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

            int index = 0;
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String whl = String.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
                String[] split = whl.split(",");
                Product p = new Product(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
                Product p2 = new Product(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
                array1.insert(p,index);
                array2.insert(p2,index);
                index++;   
            }
            array1.display();
            array2.display();
    }
```